# R replace all substrings that are websites

Tags: regex, r

I have tried

```
gsub("/^(http?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$/","","This is a website http://www.example.com/test and needs to be removed",ignore.case=T, perl=T)
```

pattern is from: [this website](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know--net-6149)

Code runs but doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: the ^$ are for matching line breaks, with the url inside a string it won't work unless you remove those

Comment: Where is the website data coming from with the urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

- `^` and `$`, which match start/end of line
- first and last `/`, which are delimiters, and are not required by gsub
- the space , which avoid you to match the url only -currently, it catch all the end of the line)

```
gsub("(http?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w\\.-]*)*\\/?","","This is a website http://www.example.com/test and needs to be removed",ignore.case=T, perl=T)
```

**[Try it](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=GIRUHzCQ&version=2)**

Answer (score 0):

The `rm_url` function from the **qdapRegex** package that  maintain is made for this.  It has the added benefit of correcting the extra white space left behind:

```
library(qdapRegex)

rm_url("This is a website http://www.example.com/test and needs to be removed")
## [1] "This is a website and needs to be removed"
```

If you're interested in what the regex is for `rm_url` you can use the `grab` function on any **qdapRegex** function that uses a single regex and learn about the expression used:

```
grab("rm_url")
## [1] "(http[^ ]*)|(ftp[^ ]*)|(www\\.[^ ]*)"
```